# Adjusting the default clipping distance on Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a large world file, and unfortunately the default clipping distance (in UserCamera.cc) is set such that I cannot view my entire world on screen.  So far, I have worked around this by:

1. Deleting the ROS_NOBUILD in the gazebo folder located in /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo
2. Performing a '$rosmake gazebo' as root <br/>
   3. Modifying the UserCamera.cc <br/>
   4. Doing a '$make', '$make install', and '$ldconfig' as root in the appropriate build folder to propagate the changes.
   While this worked on prior gazebo releases, with the newest gazebo release (1.6.16) the GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH does not seem to be set correctly after going through this process.  Besides, I would like to not have to mess around with a rosmake of gazebo (which I know is ill advised) so an alternative solution would be welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44011/adjusting-the-default-clipping-distance-on-gazebo/) by [pyrobat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3219/pyrobat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-09-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried modifying the farClip and the horizontal field of view?

e.g.

```
<hfov>90</hfov>
<nearClip>0.01</nearClip>
<farClip>100</farClip>
```

From [test_camera.urdf](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/browser/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk/gazebo_worlds/objects/test_camera.urdf)

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1